# C++ Converting Vector<BYTE> to string where first vector byte is 0

Tags: c++, string, vector, byte, zero

I am trying to convert a std::vector of BYTES (or unsigned char) to a std::string.
The problem I have is when the first element of the vector is a 0, then this returns an empty string after the conversion.

I have tried the 2 methods below. Both string1 and string2 return an empty string. 
The result I am expecting is a string that starts with 2 x 0s followed by several other characters.

```
// vector of BYTE, contains these 7 elements for example: (0,30,85,160,155,93,0)
std::vector<BYTE> data;

// method 1
BYTE* pByteArray = &data[0];
std::string string1 = reinterpret_cast<LPCSTR>(pByteArray);

// method 2
std::string string2(data.begin(),data.end());

// both string1 and string2 return ""
```

I am guessing because the first BYTE in the vector is a 0, so the string assignment is thinking it's null or empty.
Is there some other conversion I can do in order to return the rest of the string?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you determine they were empty? The second is correct (but note `std::string` uses `char`, not `unsigned char`).

Comment: Method 1 won't work because it invokes the `const char*` overload of `std::string` constructor, which stops on `\0`. Why the 2nd one didn't work is more puzzling.

Comment: Probably the 2nd method did work, but printing the string out makes it look empty.

Answer (score 8):

The second is not really empty please consider:

```
// vector of BYTE, contains these 7 elements for example: (0,30,85,160,155,93,0)
std::vector<BYTE> data = {0, 35, 35 ,38};

// method 2
std::string string2(data.begin(),data.end());
cout<< (string2.data()+1) << " size:"<< string2.size() << endl;
/* Notice that size is 4 */
```

On [ideone](http://ideone.com/p0IdeM)

**Edit** Checking the size is even more trivial as it's **4**.

---

Regarding `data` and `null` termination as the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) kindly explain (emphasis mine):

> **The returned array is null-terminated**, that is, data() and c_str() perform the same function. If empty() returns true, the pointer points
>   to a single null character.   (since C++11)

A "c++98 safe" way could look [like](http://ideone.com/IHHM0s):

```
cout.write(string2.data()+1, string2.size()-1);
```

Anyway the printing is just to demonstrate the strings "non-emptiness" :)

Comment: printing `string2.data() + 1` is not any good. `data()` is not NULL-terminated, only `c_str()` is.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, `data()` must be null-terminated. It's actually grouped with `c_str()` in the standard such that they both share the same details.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, `data()` doesn't exist in C++98. Wait, never mind. That's `std::vector::data` :/

Comment: @chris `std::string::data()` most definitely does exist in C++98 as well.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I've edited to include the doc regarding the `data()` being `null` terminated, the linked example(@ideone) did say it's c++11 and and anyway printing it was just a simple way of demonstrating the op's wrong assumption. Most probably he'll be using `data` and `size` to refer to the data held by the `string`.

Answer (score 4):

First method is wrong, however second gives correct result - string, that is null terminated. If termination mark (null) is the very first character, it looks empty, but actually it isn't.

Also, about first method, you wanted:

```
std::vector<BYTE> data;
//some code
std::string string1(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&data[0]), data.length());
```

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't have a `.length()` use `.size()`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for hex output like `0x90 0xBA 0xFF` then here's the code I've used to generate them:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_hex(T data)
{
    std::ostringstream result;
    result << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::uppercase << static_cast<int>(data);
    return result.str();
}

std::string dump(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data)
{
    if (data.empty()) return "";
    auto size = data.size();
    std::ostringstream result;
    for(u32 i =0; i < size; i++)
    {
        result << "0x" + to_hex(data[i]);
        if (i != size)
            result << " ";
    }
    return result.str();
}
```