# C++ Unable to convert std::vector<BYTE> to a string or char array

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, byte

I am currently working with the Registry using this GitHub library:

https://github.com/GiovanniDicanio/WinReg

I am trying to convert this `vector<BYTE>` to a char array or a string, to make a hash out of it with help of SHA-512. But I am stuck with converting it, I tried different methods. I don´t get any compiler errors, just the app crashes at runtime. I am using a DLL that I load into my process.

```
 RegKey NetworkInterface_key(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\\0001");

 const std::vector<BYTE> InstallTimeStamp = NetworkInterface_key.GetBinaryValue(L"InstallTimeStamp");
```

---

MY SOLUTION:

Changed `std::vector<BYTE>`  -> `std::vector<unsigned char>`

Used this methode:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_hex(T data)
{
    std::ostringstream result;
    result << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::uppercase << static_cast<int>(data);
    return result.str();
}

std::string dump(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data)
{
    if (data.empty()) return "";
    auto size = data.size();
    std::ostringstream result;
    for(u32 i =0; i < size; i++)
    {
        result << "0x" + to_hex(data[i]);
        if (i != size)
            result << " ";
    }
    return result.str();
}
```

Credits: U. Bulle -> [C++ Converting Vector<BYTE> to string where first vector byte is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015126/c-converting-vectorbyte-to-string-where-first-vector-byte-is-0)

Comment: You did not show the code that crashes while trying to convert the `vector` to a string or char array.

Comment: MY SOLUTION: Changed std::vector<BYTE>  -> std::vector<unsigned char>

Comment: `BYTE` is just an alias for `unsigned char`, so that change doesn't solve anything. Your "solution" is merely printing the vector to a hex encoded string. It has nothing to do with using the vector for hashing, which was the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that library, just do this:

```
HKEY key = 0;
BYTE timestamp[16] = { 0 };
LRESULT err = ::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\\0001", 0, KEY_READ, &key);
if (err == 0)
{
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD dwSize = 16;
    ::RegQueryValueEx(key, L"InstallTimeStamp", NULL, &dwType, timestamp, &dwSize);
    RegCloseKey(key);
}
```

As for converting those 16 bytes into "string".  That doesn't make a lot of sense given that that those 16 bytes are binary data.  You could do this:

```
std::string strTimestamp((char*)timestamp, 16);
```

But I suspect you just want a pointer to pass to a sha512 function that expects a `char*` data type.  If that's the case, just do this:

```
const char* ts = (char*)timestamp;
```

Just remember the length of that array is fixed and is not a null terminated string. So your hash function should take a length parameter as well.

Comment: In your last example, you should use `reinterpret_cast` instead of a C-style cast: `const char* ts = reinterpret_cast<char*>(timestamp);` Or, you could just use a `char[]` array instead: `char timestamp[16] = {}; ... ::RegQueryValueEx(..., reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(timestamp), ...);`

Comment: Thanks for solution,i knew that but i was working with a lot of entry was just annoying the wrapper was quiet handy.

Answer (score 0):

The `RegKey::GetBinaryValue()` method returns a `std::vector<BYTE>`.  To convert that data to a `char[]` array, you don't really have to actually convert it at all, you can simply type-cast a pointer to the data instead:

```cpp
const std::vector<BYTE> InstallTimeStamp = ...;
const char *pInstallTimeStamp = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(InstallTimeStamp.data());
```

But, if you want to convert the data to a `std::string`, then `std::string` has constructors that are appropriate for that purpose, eg:

```cpp
const std::vector<BYTE> InstallTimeStamp = ...;
std::string sInstallTimeStamp(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(InstallTimeStamp.data()), InstallTimeStamp.size());
```

```cpp
const std::vector<BYTE> InstallTimeStamp = ...;
std::string sInstallTimeStamp(InstallTimeStamp.begin(), InstallTimeStamp.end());
```

However, that being said, hashes operate on bytes, not on characters or strings, so you really should not need to convert the `vector` data to anything else at all, just hash its contents as-is.  Unless you are using a hashing API that requires `char`/`string` input (if so, you should find a better hash API), in which case the above should suffice.

Comment: Tried them already before 1:1 same getting issues code crash my app on runtime. Now i have solution will post it on my question as answer.

Comment: @suspex0 don't post your solution in the original question. Post an actual answer for it instead. You can [post answers to your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).